# Все переменные массивов отображаются как - Undefined variable. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

почему-то мне он подчёркивает переменные массивов и в браузере выдаёт ошибки.
Суть задания: "Отсортируйте элементы полученного массива так, чтобы вначале массива были фрукты, а только потом ягоды. Причем между собой фрукты  и ягоды отсортированы по длине названия от самого короткого к самому длинному."
При наведении на ошибку: Undefined variable "$fruitrs"(название переменных короче) и я не знаю почему undefined. Они же должны быть доступны
Вот сортировка и массивы:

```
 $vegetables = ['Картошка','Капуста','Морковка'];
    $fruits = ['Банан','Яблоко','Апельсин'];
    $berries = ['Вишня', 'Малина', 'Виноград'];// задание 6
usort($combined_elements, function($a, $b) {
        if(
            in_array($a, $fruits) &&
            in_array($b, $berries)
        ){
            return -1;
        } elseif(in_array($a, $berries) && in_array($b, $fruits)
        ){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return strlen($a) <=> strlen($b);
        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тупанул, нужно было `use($fruits, $berries)` добавить после `function($a, $b)`

```
usort($combined_elements, function($a, $b) use($fruits, $berries){

});
```

вот так